# Indexed collection still scanning all rows for simple lookups

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document structure in a fairly large mongodb collection (on the order of 10 million documents):

```
{
    _id: <ObjectId>,
    p: [
         "user A"
         "user B"
    ],
    data: "not important"
}
```

The "p" field indicates the two user IDs whose data this belongs to (think of this as a collection of conversations among pairs of users). It's always an array of 2 user IDs and is unique (no other document has the same pair of users in its "p" field).

I have an index on this field:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "p" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "mydb.messages",
    "name" : "p_1",
    "background" : true,
    "safe" : true
}
```

The problem is that when I do lookups in my application, mongodb is scanning all possible rows. For example, user A might have 2800 other conversations, and when I perform the following query just to find the conversation with one other specific user, it scans all 2800 rows:

```
db.messages.find({p: ["user A", "user B"]});
```

Here's the explain output:

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor p_1 multi",
"isMultiKey" : true,
"n" : 0,
"nscannedObjects" : 2805,
"nscanned" : 2806,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2805,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 2806,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 23,
"indexBounds" : {
    "p" : [
        [
            "user A",
            "user A"
        ],
        [
            [
                "user A",
                "user B"
            ],
            [
                "user A",
                "user B"
            ]
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "ip-10-237-195-23:27017"
}
```

I have subbed actual user ID strings with user A and user B for readability.

As there's lots of these queries this is a serious drag on performance. I'm assuming I haven't indexed the field properly, or the index just doesn't perform as expected on fields containing arrays. In any case, any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: For starters, you should be using `$all` as in `{ "p": { "$all": [ "user A", "user B"] } }` otherwise your query can only match elements that are **exactly** formed `["userA", "userB"]` with only those elements in the same order. Also are these just values in the array, or are they actually objects with properties of their own?

Comment: I sort the two "p" members on insert and also on query to be certain they are querying in the same order. They are just string values, not objects. Would using $all still help in this case?